# Setting nextFireTime of a quartz job manually in groovy

Tags: groovy, quartz-scheduler

I want to use a own errorhandling on quartz jobs. Each job has a different waiting time, when an exception occurs. For example, a job runs every 30 seconds, but when an exception occurs, the job should wait for 5 minutes.

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory()
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler()        
def name = "jobname"
Trigger trigger = sched.getTrigger(new TriggerKey("trigger_" + name))
def currentDate = new Date()
use (TimeCategory) {
    currentDate = currentDate + 300.seconds
}
trigger.nextFireTime = currentDate
```

The job runs in 30 seconds again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but are you sure you can schedule a job by simply setting the `nextFireTime` property?

I guess you have to use http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#rescheduleJob(org.quartz.TriggerKey, org.quartz.Trigger) do reschedule a job.

e.g.

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory()
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler()        
def name = "jobname"
Trigger trigger = sched.getTrigger(new TriggerKey("trigger_" + name))
trigger.repeatInterval = 30000
sched.rescheduleJob(trigger.name, trigger.group, trigger)
```

That would run the job in 5 minutes and then you'd have to reschedule it to run in 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a pity that there is no simply solution.